# Is it possible to modify and extend CodeLens by a VS 2013 Plugin?

Tags: c#, plugins, visual-studio-2013, codelens

And if so - how? And if not - are there any news on whether or not and when it will be open for modification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no public extensibility point for CodeLens at this time.   There's a uservoice item tracking this, though, so i'd vote and comment there:

http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6518006-expose-an-api-to-be-able-to-extend-or-take-advanta